# show the expiry time

Tags: html, css

[image]

```
 <td valign="bottom"> 
    <div style="width: 205px;height: 21px;border: 1px solid;">
       <div style="height: 21px;background-color:#5f5f5f; background-size: 100px 10px;">                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

    </div></div><br>
<span style="font-size:11px;">*Valid for 1 year from the date of purchase</span>
</td>
```

The above image , i have send it . i need the things like this in html , I have made a div and use background-color but it covers the whole portion but i want to cover the background only 30% or any % i want . Is there any kind of help u can give me

Comment: PLease explain what exactly you're trying to do. Your question is very hard to understand.

Comment: I think he is trying to make a progress bar which displays the time left before expiration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you need only one `DIV` element (instead of two):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/oWoYObE/3/edit)**

```
<div class="expirationBar"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.expirationBar{
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  width: 205px;
  height:21px;
  border-radius:3px;
  background: #eee url(//placehold.it/1x1/5f5f5f) repeat-y;
  background-size: 30%;
}
```

---

...but to get to your exact issue:

Instead of `background-size` use `width`

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/oWoYObE/1/edit)**

```
<div style="height: 21px; background-color:#5f5f5f; width:30%;">
```

for the inner DIV

You're not using any image, so you don't have any `background-size` to apply to, cause it refers to images.

**Otherwise**, using images - than you can set it like:

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/oWoYObE/2/edit)**

```
<div style="background:url('10x10_gray.jpg') repeat-y; background-size:30%; height:21px; "></div>
```